# Neumann boundary condition for Laplace's equation in 2D axisymmetric coordinates?

Tags: boundary-conditions, thermal-conductivity, diffusion

I have the Laplace's equation, say, describing the density $\rho(r,z)$ distribution in a 2D axisymmetric coordinate:

$$\nabla^2 \rho=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial z^2}=0,$$

where $r$ and $z$ are the radial and axial coordinates.

To impose a constant gradient of density condition **at infinity**, I came up with the following two kinds of conditions:

**Neumann BC.1**

\begin{equation}
  \lim_{l \to +\infty}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r}=
\lim_{l \to +\infty}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}=c, \quad \mbox{with} \quad l=(r^2+z^2)^{1/2};
\end{equation}

**Neumann BC.2**
\begin{equation}
  \lim_{l \to +\infty}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \mathbf{n}}
=\lim_{l \to +\infty}\frac{r\rho_r+z\rho_z}{l}=c, \quad \mbox{with} \quad l=(r^2+z^2)^{1/2},
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a constant, $\mathbf{n}=l^{-1}(r,z)$ is the unit normal of the circle $l=(r^2+z^2)^{1/2}$.

Can anyone suggest me which one is correct or both of them are wrong? Thank you in advance.

Actually, I have posted this question on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190784/how-to-specify-a-neumann-boundary-condition-for-laplaces-equation-in-2d-axisymm), but it has received few attentions, thus I'd like to post my question here because it possesses a general physical meaning associated with diffusion or conduction processes.

Comment: Neither condition you wrote can be described as "constant gradient of density condition". The former says that at infinity the two non-angular components of the gradient are in fact constant, but there is the further constraint that these components are equal. The latter condition does not regard the gradient at infinity but only the normal component of it referred to a larger and larger spherical surface of equation $l=(r^2+z^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti thanks. Did you think the latter is going to be closer to what I want? Could we regard the latter as a directional derivative in the normal $\mathbf{n}$ direction of the larger and larger spherical surface? And the directional derivative was taken to be constant $c$ at infinity. Could you pls give some advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, I think the latter is closer to your idea. The gradient along the normal direction is constant at infinity...

Comment: @ValterMoretti,  the boundary of my ''diffusion source'' is an upward convex axisymmetric surface, so I feel that it could be convenient for solving a Laplace's eq. in an upper semi-spherical domain instead of a square domain. That's why I wanted such a BC imposed on a spherical surface. Btw, by imposing the BC.2, can I only state that the density gradient **along the normal direction** is constant at infinity, instead of density gradient being constant at infinity?